# toggle visibility of icon upon success with jquery

Tags: jquery, element, show, hidden

Strange thing. I have a some dinamically created forms in which I insert unique id span near the submit button like this:

```
"<span id=\"successful_insert"+ obj.models[i].id +"\"  style=\"display: none;\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></span>"
```

result in html is for example:

```
<span id="successful_insert466" style="display: none;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

So in this particular form I get `id="successful_insert466"`

The glyphicon is hidden by default, so after hitting submit I want the icon to show up.
I use:

```
success: function () {
             $("#" + span).fadeIn("slow");
         }
```

Where `span` is a variable that I get like this:

```
var form = $(this);
var span = $(form).find('input[name="span_id"]').val();
span = String(span);
```

The point is the glyphicon remains hidden, the function is not working. What's the catch?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the following line.

```
var span = $(form).find('input[name="span_id"]').val();
```

You should wrap `form` with single quotes like below.

```
var span = $('form').find('input[name="span_id"]').val();
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that form is a variable too `var form = $(this);` and if I console log `span` I get what I need.

Comment: OK. Are you getting the value of `span` before `ajax` call? @Chriz74

Comment: In `ajax` success console log span and see what are you getting. @Chriz74

Comment: interestingly enough I don't get anything... is this a scope problem?

Comment: May be. You can create a fiddle with your full code. @Chriz74

Comment: wait, I changed something in my controller and it's working now, I'll inspect my code.

Comment: I removed return `Response()->json($values);` earlier as I didn't need those `$values` anymore now I reinstated the `Response()->json();` after a database operation in my controller at the end of the `store` function and it started working. I don't understand what's the purpose of returning a response without data.

Comment: I don't know,  may be if there is no response `ajax` `succes` will not work. @Chriz74

Comment: ok but `Response()->json();` returns an empty object, I tried to simply `return true;` and I get an internal server error 500

Comment: I think you are using `PHP` in server side. I don't know `PHP`. But I think your method return type is `object` not `boolean`. @Chriz74

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of `String(span)`? I think that might be throwing it off. `String(span)` is creating a string object, not a string literal, so when you add it into `$("#" + span)` I think it may be getting more information in the jQuery selector than you want. Try removing that line and see what happens.

Comment: I did as you suggested but nothing changed

Comment: I'm assuming that your input that is holding the span id contains the prepended "successful_insert" as well as the unique number, is that correct?

Comment: wait, I changed something in my controller and now it's working

Comment: Hard telling with only a small snippet of the code to look at, but my guess is that an id was off somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue with your selector expression :

`find('input[name="span_id"]')`  -> you are looking for an element of type `input` with name attribute as `'span_id'` => No such element exists. So you either want to target the element with id selector ( `#successful_insert466` ) or contains selector ( `[id=successful_insert466]` )

```
$(document).find('span[id=successful_insert466]').fadeIn("slow");

or  $(document).find('#successful_insert466').fadeIn("slow");
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ovtajgok/